# Can't figure out how to join two MariaDB tables with PHP to display

Tags: php, mysql, join, mariadb

I want to join FACILITY and INSPECTION so that it shows the score and some other information next to the facility's name, address, and phone number. I think I have my foreign keys set up correctly, but my professor hasn't been much help in confirming that. Here are my SQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE FACILITY(
County           VARCHAR(45)    NOT NULL    ,
Phone_Number           VARCHAR(12)  NOT NULL    ,
Name            VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL    ,
Address     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL    ,
ID        VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL   ,
UNIQUE(ID),
PRIMARY KEY(Address));

CREATE TABLE INSPECTION(
Inspection_date DATE            NOT NULL    ,
Score           INT         NOT NULL    ,
Facility_ID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
Inspector_ID        VARCHAR(9)             NOT NULL ,
Inspection_ID       CHAR(9)     NOT NULL    ,
UNIQUE(Facility_ID),
PRIMARY KEY(Inspection_ID));

ALTER TABLE INSPECTION
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(Facility_ID) REFERENCES FACILITY(ID);
```

And here is the line of PHP I am using to try and join them

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SELECT * FROM FACILITY JOIN INSPECTION USING(Facility_ID)")
   or die (mysqli_error($dbconnect));
```

The error I get is:

```
Unknown column 'Facility_ID' in 'from clause'
```

Thanks for the help, I bet the solution is something pretty simple, I just have very little sql and php experience.

Comment: Never create a key as `VARCHAR`.  Why not use `INT`?

Comment: And what is `WHERE FACILITY.ID = INSPECTION.Facility_ID` for?

Comment: A `USING(column)` expects that column to be in both tables.

Comment: @Eric - not `WHERE`, `ON`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only join with `USING` if the column name in both tables is the same. They aren't, because it's called `ID` in your `FACILITY` table.

In this case, you need to use `ON` for your join:

```
SELECT * FROM FACILITY JOIN INSPECTION ON INSPECTION.Facility_ID = FACILITY.ID
```